# Field order on query MySQL from Clojure JDBC

Tags: clojure

When I query MySQL from Clojure (jdbc), the fields are not returned in the order specified in SELECT clause (I'm calling a stored procedure that does the select). Initially it seemed that the fields were returned in the reverse order, but this happens only if there are 1 to 9 fields. Adding the tenth field makes the result set to go in no particular order, altough it is always the same order for a particular number of fields in result set.

Anyone has observed it?

Comment: Could you show us some code?  I've never done this in Clojure.  Are you use a java jdbc library or a clojure library?

Comment: What is the data type returned by the query? The reordering based on extra results sounds similar to what happens to the order of the keys when more items are added to a hash map. When I do jdbc queries the results are coming back in a vector in whatever order I told sql to put them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask [java.jdbc](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc) to return individual rows as vectors rather than maps (or arrays, in spite of the option name) by passing `:as-arrays? true` to `query`; field order will then be preserved:

```
;; checked with java.jdbc 0.3.0-alpha4
(query db [sql params...] :as-arrays? true)
```

Note that in this mode of operation an extra vector containing the keys corresponding to the column names (which would otherwise be used in the constructed maps) will be prepended to the seq of actual result vectors.

By default, java.jdbc returns rows as maps, as per Arthur's answer. These will be array maps up to 9 entries (maintaining insertion order) and hash maps beyond this threshold (with no useful ordering).

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that the fields are being returned in order and then subsequently being re-orderd by the data structure they are packed into by the clojure jdbc library. Assuming you are using clojure.java.jdbc the results are returned in a list of maps like this:

```
{:name "Apple" :appearance "rosy" :cost 24}
{:name "Orange" :appearance "round" :cost 49}
```

where each map is one row. The order of the rows will be preserved because they are presented in a list, though the order of the fields is not because they are presented in maps (which do not guarantee order. You could sort them afterwords if you need a particular order or call