# Clojure postgres sql query is ignoring SELECT ordering

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I am using the following library: `[org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1201-jdbc41"]` to connect to my database, and i am querying using the following query:

```
select
    happenedat,
    "_customer.email",
    ismobile,
    "_customer.title",
    "_customer.firstname",
    "_customer.lastname",
    "_eventdata.park.name",
    "_customer.address line 1",
    "_customer.address line 2",
    "_customer.address town",
    "_customer.address county",
    "_customer.postcode",
    "_customer.telephone number"
from my_table
where eventaction = 'brochure request'
and happenedat > (getdate() - 5)
and happenedat < getdate()
and ("_customer.email" is not null or "_customer.firstname" is not null or "_customer.lastname" is not null or "_customer.postcode" is not null)
order by 7,1
```

If I used an application for running this such as `Postico` then the query returns as expected, however if I run this using `Clojure` and the following:

```
defn write-query-to-csv [query db output-filename]
  (log/info (str "Executing " query " on " db))
  (let [results (query db)
        header (->> results
                    first
                    keys
                    (map name)
                    (into []))
        data (->> results
                  (map #(vec (vals %))))]
    (with-open [out-file (io/writer output-filename)]
      (csv/write-csv out-file
                     (reduce conj (conj [] header) data)))
    (io/file output-filename)))
```

Which writes the query to CSV, however the ordering of the `SELECT` fields is completely wrong, the order of these is not maintained.

I read here: [Similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16556998/5090232) that its because the result is returned as an unordered map and you need to return them as an array, but isn't `(into [])` putting each result into an array which should maintain ordering?

Comment: I haven't tried this out, but I think that the problem is that the result is already unordered map. Therefore applying (into []) on something that is already unordered won't give you correct order.

Comment: @ViktorK. yeah I think your correct, any idea how to order the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is to use the `[clojure.java.jdbc]` library and add `:as-arrays? true` Which returns the results in order.